# UrlScan Config Change Not Working?

Tags: iis, iis-7, url

I installed UrlScan a few days ago and it seemed to be working fine, however in the log I saw it was blocking lots of files from websites that I didn't want ([Explanation here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/09/26/url-scan-broke-my-blog.aspx/))

It's blocking files with Dots in the URL (Especially assets like .js files and .css files). So it broke a lot of sites.

So I changed the following as per the docs and that blog post.

```
AllowDotInPath=0
```

to

```
AllowDotInPath=1
```

And restarted IIS, but nothing changed. It's still blocking Dots in paths. And then I restarted the entire server... And guess what. It's still blocking dots in path?

I have no idea what to do next, apart from un-install it? Anyone else this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It appears there has to be a blank line before the `[Options]` section. Without this blank line I was not able to get any of the settings in this section to work, as soon as I i added it everything worked fine.

It is also possible to replace the first blank line by a comment (starting with `;`).

Tested with UrlScan 3.1 and IIS 7.5

Answer (score 1):

You can also just remove URLScan from the ISAPI filters for that specific website, if you don't want the vulnerability affecting the whole server.

IIS Manager / Server / Sites / YourSite / IIS / ISAPI Filters, select "URLScan" and click "Remove" on the righthand action menu.